# C# - Verify client certificate signed by proper root

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I know there are a lot of questions on this argument but I'm stuck into this for several days now so here I am.
I've got a root certificate and a client certificate. I need to replicate in a C# web API project what the command `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client.pem` does.

This is what i know for now (hope it's actually true):

- `Verify()` method actually validate that the certificate is signed by an authority. It's like a format control. It doesn't matter which autority signed the certificate.
- `X509 Chain` is the way to go. Add your ca certificate inside an extra store because i'm not going to install the certificate into Windows. Then build passing the client certificate. Let's the magic happens! Unfortunately I've got some problems with the configuration.

Let me be more clear with an example

```
private bool VerifyCertificate(X509Certificate2 client)
{
    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    var stringCert = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CACertificate"];
    var byteCert = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringCert);
    var authority = new X509Certificate2(byteCert);

    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreWrongUsage;

    chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(authority);

    // Do the preliminary validation.
    if (!chain.Build(client))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

With this example the program returns `false`. The build is not passed. I'm sure the problem is with the `ChainPolicy properties` so i tried a different configuration

```
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
```

But this one is not going to verify **anything**, in fact using my ca cert the method returns `true` and using another ca certificate (which i didn't use to signed my client certificate) the method also returns `true`.

I Searched for an OpenSSL wrapper for C# and i found it but unfortunately is based on old libraries and the repo isn't manteined anymore. Also, i would achieve my goal using just .net framework if possible.

So guys, fast recap. I want to check that only the certificate that is firmed by my ca certificate can pass the validation, all the others must be stopped.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the problem.
In my case this was the right response.

```
 private bool VerifyCertificate(X509Certificate2 client)
    {
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        var stringCert = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CACertificate"];
        var byteCert = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringCert);
        var authority = new X509Certificate2(byteCert);

        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;

        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(authority);

        // Do the preliminary validation.
        if (!chain.Build(client))
            return false;

        // This piece makes sure it actually matches your known root
        var valid = chain.ChainElements
            .Cast<X509ChainElement>()
            .Any(x => x.Certificate.Thumbprint == authority.Thumbprint);

        if (!valid)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Now, debugging the application i have some considerations:

1. What the .Build() method is supposed to do?

I mean, using the certificate that is signed by the ca or using the self-signed certificate the method Always returns `true` BUT if i use the trusted one it will add the certificate inside the `chain.ChainElements`otherwise nothing is added.

I need to understand this thing but all the test I've done said the method works

Comment: Did you ever found an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: The above code, does it work as intended? It is the only way i can get it to work with Cloudflare :)

Answer (score 3):

`ExtraStore` isn't limiting, it provides extra certificates to help complete the chain.  It provides no trust data.

In order to determine if the certificate is issued by the CA that you want you need to do something like:

```
private static readonly X509Certificate2 s_trustedRoot = ObtainTheRoot();
private static readonly byte[] s_normalizedRoot = s_trustedRoot.RawData;

private bool VerifyCertificate(X509Certificate2 candidate)
{
    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    // set all the things you need to set to make it build

    if (!chain.Build(candidate))
        return false;

    // Check that the root certificate was the expected one.
    X509ChainElementCollection elements = chain.ChainElements;
    return elements[elements.Count - 1].Certificate.RawData.SequenceEqual(s_normalizedRoot);
}
```

I promoted the cert and normalized byte form of it to statics on the assumption that they don't change once the process starts.  If the cert can change dynamically then you should adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi, you may be right but the answer isn't flly answered. The point is, how can i make it build a certificate only signed by a proper ca? Isn't the build method just a 'structural' check of the certificate properties?

Comment: @BlackShawarna Build says that the chain built, wasn’t expired, the root was trusted, etc (except for any checks suppressed with chain.ChainPolixy.ValidationFlags). The specific CA check is the part after, where you compare the bytes of the chain element with the answer you are willing to accept. (Last one for root, second one for direct issuer, etc)

Comment: What does "ExtraStore isn't limiting, it provides extra certificates to help complete the chain. It provides no trust data." mean here? I am a bit confused with "it provides no trust data".

Comment: @mslot A cert being provided in ExtraStore doesn’t mean the chain will necessarily say “the chain is trusted”, and ExtraStore can provide a lot of certs that don’t get used, and the chain can be successful without using ExtraStore at all. It’s just... extra :)